# Fish shell: append argument to an existing function

Tags: shell, fish

I want to add `--group-directories-first` to `ls` command. If in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` I can define an alias like this one:

```
alias ls "ls --group-directories-first"
```

but it overwrites fish shell's `ls` function definition:

```
function ls --description 'List contents of directory'
    set -l param --color=auto
    if isatty 1
        set param $param --indicator-style=classify
    end
    command ls $param $argv
end
```

I can redefine `ls` function in order to add the needed argument:

```
function ls --description 'List contents of directory'
    set -l param --color=auto --group-directories-first
    if isatty 1
        set param $param --indicator-style=classify
    end
    command ls $param $argv
end
```

But I don't like this solution: what I want is to redefine `ls` in order to call the previous `ls` function with an argument. Is there a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could <strike>rename</strike> copy fish's ls function:

```
functions --copy ls __fish_ls
```

Then use that in your function:

```
alias ls '__fish_ls --group-directories-first'
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept this answer if any better answer will be submitted

Answer (score 2):

abbr  ls "ls --group-directories-first"

??

Comment: Hello! This isn't bad at all, but what I really want is `ls` *to implicitly include* `--group-directories-first`, instead of completing to that